# addrelativeforce() adds regular force in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float speed = 100f;
    [SerializeField] float rotationspeed = 10f;
    Rigidbody rb;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        ProcessThrust();
        ProcessRotate();
    }

    void ProcessThrust()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
       {
           rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);
       }
    }
 
    void ProcessRotate() 
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
       {
           ApplyRotation(rotationspeed);
       }

        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
       {
           ApplyRotation(-rotationspeed);
       }
    }

    private void ApplyRotation(float rotationThisFrame) 
    {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * rotationThisFrame * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    



}
```

my object moves straight up even when i rotate it?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to rather do both in `FixedUpdate`. Also in general do not Mix physics (Rigidbody) with direct transformation via the `Transform` component .. rather use e.g. [`Rigidbody.MoveRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html)

Something like e.g.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float speed = 100f;
    [SerializeField] private float rotationspeed = 10f;
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody rb;
    
    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!rb) rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        ProcessThrust();
        ProcessRotate();
    }

    void ProcessThrust()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
 
    void ProcessRotate() 
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            ApplyRotation(rotationspeed);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            ApplyRotation(-rotationspeed);
        }
    }

    private void ApplyRotation(float rotationThisFrame) 
    {
        rb.MoveRotation(rb.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.forward * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i am currently following a tutorial which this code worked very well for them, id rather know what i was doing wrong so i could keep following the tutorial to avoid complications further in